# What should I look at to check compatibility between motherboard and PCIe devices?

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, pci-express

If I have a motherboard and want to know if a card (in this case an LSI SAS controller card) will be compatible with it, how can I know for sure?

It physcially fits, has the right lane count (port has 16x, card needs 8x; Motherboard supports Gen 1, 2, 3, cards, this card is 8x rev 2.0).

Comment: PCI-E is PCI-E if your motherboard supports PCI-S devices then it supports the card, OS support, is another story.

Comment: What I have is an LSI external SAS controller, however its boot BIOS isn't showing up when the system boots up, motivating my question.

Comment: The card is compatible with your motherboard

Comment: May this link of Hardware Compatibility helps you:
https://wiki.lime-technology.com/Hardware_Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility in this case came down to firmware version on the SAS controller card not working with the motherboard BIOS/UEFI. While I have no more information on why the old firmware was incompatible, an upgrade made the card usable. For more information, see these answers:

https://serverfault.com/questions/888663/compatibility-criteria-between-pcie-component-and-the-motherboard/889110

[Is it meaningful to have an EFI/UEFI boot disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/1278833/is-it-meaningful-to-have-an-efi-uefi-boot-disk/1278893#1278893)